# bar plot dataset with parameters in r

Tags: r, math

I have a table

```
a ,b, V1
date1 ,2 ,3
date2 ,4 ,1
date3 ,2 ,3
date4 ,5 ,1
date5 ,2 ,3
```

I need to build a plot that shows how often the same value `b` is repeated every day from the  `V1>2`.( show number of b with V1>2 for every day)
To find the number of repetitions, I used `ddply (num.csv,. (Generator), nrow)`.

I tried `barplot(worSet$V1, names.arg = worSet$b)` but it not right i want. 
And `b` is a charaster name

Comment: There does not seem to be any c in your example data.

Comment: This? `library(tidyverse);
d %>% 
  filter(V1>2) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(b))) + 
    geom_histogram(stat="count")`

Comment: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (357892): x

Comment: and i need count of b  repitions for every day, for plot as factor